# Increase count from given id number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, increment

Working with two sheets in Google Sheets. I would like to have a script attached to a button that would take an id number generated in cell "H2" on `sheet2`, lookup/find the id in column B on `sheet1`, select that row, and then increase the value by 1 for the cell in column E of the selected row.

I do know how to create a button and attach the script.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work:

1. Copy mybuttonsiderbar.html code into a new html file named 'mybuttonsiderbar'.
2. Run the showsiderbar() function and see the new sidebar.
3. Click the Increment Button

mybuttonsiderbar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function goIncrement()
      {
        google.script.run.goInc();
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Increment" onClick="goIncrement();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function goInc() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var v=sh2.getRange('H2').getValue();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(vA[i][2]==v)
    {
      var current=sh1.getRange(i+1,5).getValue()
      sh1.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(Number(current + 1));
      break;
    }
  }
  sh1.getRange(i+1,1).activate();
}

function showSiderBar()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mybuttonsiderbar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```